# How to add foreign key constraint that affects multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables in MySQL 8.x:

keywords:

```
    ID | keyword

PK: ID
```

keyword_filter:

```
    KW_ID | SKU

PK: KW_ID, SKU
```

Now I want to set a foreign key on ID referencing KW_ID with the intention that all filters for a particular ID get updated/removed once the keyword gets updated/removed.
There can be multiple identical KW_IDs as long as KW_ID and SKU are unique.

Is this even possible or does this only work for one row? I am getting the error:

> [1451] Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Setting the foreign key worked since I disabled foreign key checks and enabled them again after altering the structure. However the error apears if I update the ID e.g. so in fact the constrain does not work as intended.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, and can set up the schema as you appear to want: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7417d0d7a8f9335691f47eb2bcfea809

Comment: Looks like it is the other way around. You have set a FK on keyword_filter instead of keyword. Use case is, that changes within the leading table "keywords" will affect the keyword_filter table not the other way around.

Comment: If you set the referential action on the foreign key any changes you make to keyword would be cascaded to the child table. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84c97320560afb6a0f0211aa77174302). If this is again not what you mean, please can you add some actual code to the question to demonstrate the issue you are having? Seeing the error message without the code is only half of the problem.

Comment: I created a fiddle with some example data that illustrates the problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96bdcfb0fe55fc36aa4ff005d9c59a67

Comment: If you add the referential integrity trigger action [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-referential-actions) to your foreign key definition the error goes away - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=339cef3f1138b00616ffd8dd9200a871

Comment: Thank you! You are right, I oversaw that setting in DataGrip as the UI is hiding it. This solved the problem.